# Regular Expression with intact text

Tags: regex, jedit

Im using Jedit and regular expression to replace some text in several code from files.

There are a lot of similar start and ends like:

```
Something
Text Sample
Something Else
```

Or

```
Something
I dont know what else
Something Else
```

Then I search using:

```
Something
[^‰\r\n]*
Something Else
```

And I want to replace all lines with:

```
Something
<Tuv Lang="EN-US">**ORIGINAL TEXT**</Tuv><Tuv Lang="PT-BR"> </Tuv>
Something Else
```

So it will add some code in the beggining and at the end of the middle text line that is not always equal.

I have tried using:

```
Something
<Tuv Lang="EN-US">[^‰\r\n]*</Tuv><Tuv Lang="PT-BR"> </Tuv>
Something Else
```

But without success.  Can somebody tell me how is the correct regular expression should I use?

Thanks in advance!

Matias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your search to:

```
Something
([^‰\r\n]*)
Something Else
```

This should 'capture' what's inside the brackets and store it in a variable, `$1`.

Then, try this replace:

```
Something
<Tuv Lang="EN-US">$1</Tuv><Tuv Lang="PT-BR"> </Tuv>
Something Else
```

I can't say if this will work I jEdit or not since I don't have it through.

Answer (score 0):

Search:

```
Something(\s*)(.*?)(\s*)Something Else
```

Replace:

```
Something$1<Tuv Lang="EN-US">$2</Tuv><Tuv Lang="PT-BR"> </Tuv>$3Something Else
```

This captures the newline(s) as well as the wrapped text and puts it all back in the right place, meaning that whatever newline chars are present are preserved.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/AdB4HfynpF) of regex matching sample input

Comment: Note the [`?` non-greedy modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) which is important if two chunks are in a single file.

Comment: I have test it but it doesnt work.  It is replaced but without words/text (where you add $2).  Anyway thanks both of you for the answers! BTW I will take a look at the live demo page you send, it looks nice!

Comment: Try using `\1` instead of `$1` etc in the replacement text. There's no standard for back references - your tool might be the backslash variety